# Difference between limit points and closure points (via diagrams)

Tags: real-analysis

Can someone please explain the difference between these concepts with pictures rather than definitions? I have seen the definitions many times, but I'm finding it hard to visualise.

Thanks in advance for the responses.

Comment: These are abstract concepts defined for arbitrary topological spaces which need not have any visual interpretation. You need to understand the *definitions* in mathematics.

Comment: Yes, but they are also defined, in particular, for some nice concrete topological spaces that *do* have a visual representation. And, understanding the special cases is a good step towards understanding the general abstract concepts. Mathematics is more than just deriving abstract consequences from abstract definitions (unless you happen to be Bourbaki).

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a picture where you can visualize the most the closure and limit points of a set, i used the Euclidean topology $\tau_e$ with the set $K$={$\frac{1}{n}$, n $\in$ $\mathbb{N^*}$}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQILz.jpg)